# How to efficiently rotate an env map used in an IBL pipeline?

Tags: three.js

I use an equirectangular EXR image to light my scenes. To achieve this, I re-used the code found in this threejs [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=envmap#webgl_materials_envmaps_exr). This works as expected.

Now, I want users to be able to rotate this map around the vertical axis in real time.
After looking at the code of the loader [EquirectangularToCubeGenerator.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/EquirectangularToCubeGenerator.js), I figured out that I could rotate the boxMesh around the Y-axis using this simple code:

`var radRotation = Math.PI;
this.boxMesh.rotateY(radRotation);`

That works OK for a set angle however it doesn't work for angles changing in real time. It is too slow as it reloads the texture and goes through the generation process for every new value.

Is there a simple and fast way to change the rotation for an environment map already generated?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hack: `scene.add( camera ); scene.rotation.y += 0.01;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works well when the camera doesn't have any controls attached. With OrbitControls, I think that there is an issue due to the lookAt function (position of camera remains similar but quaternion is updated).

Comment: I could make it work by rotating the OrbitControls target around the axis as well. However OrbitControls remains buggy when the camera view reaches the poles. As mentioned in WestLangley's comment, that is a hack.

Comment: Hello @Scrubs! Have you solved this problem? Im stuck [with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616242/issue-with-scene-rotation-in-three-js) for a long time

Comment: Yes, I even recently updated it for the new threejs PMREM Generator. Solution can be found [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/rotate-equirectangular-environment-map-with-new-pmrem-generator/11980)