# Issue with scene rotation in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to rotate a scene with children dynamically. everything works fine, but when I pan the camera and rotate scene, the pivot point from the orbit control breaks and pan works not correctly. The main idea is to create the illusion of hdr rotation around objects. Sorry for my english, its really hard to describe, hope you understand my mind.

Here a small codepen [example](https://codepen.io/vinar22/pen/dyoVZxj)

```js
var container = document.getElementById('three');
var width = container.offsetWidth;
var height = container.offsetHeight;
var range = document.getElementById('r');
var sceneChildren = new THREE.Group();
var rotationY = 0;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(width, height);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI * 45 / 180;


var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 10000);
camera.position.y = 160;
camera.position.z = 400;
camera.lookAt(cube.position);

sceneChildren.add(cube, camera);
scene.add(sceneChildren)

var skyboxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000);
var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xf3f3f3f3, side: THREE.BackSide });
var skybox = new THREE.Mesh(skyboxGeometry, skyboxMaterial);

scene.add(skybox);

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xff33fff);
pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);


var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight2.position.set(0, -300, 200);

scene.add(pointLight, pointLight2);

var clock = new THREE.Clock;

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.screenSpacePanning = true;

range.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  rotationY = e.target.value
})

function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        sceneChildren.rotation.y = rotationY;
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

```css
#three {
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
}
#r {
  z-index: 99999;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.101.1/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
Rotate scene children <input type="range" min="0" max="60" step="0.01" id="r">
<div id="three"></div>
```

**---update---**

Steps to display the problem:
 1. Rotate scene children via range input
 2. Pan camera via right click of your mouse (pivot point breaks down at this step)
 3. Rotate scene children again (you can see that the camera no longer rotates with the cube)

Comment: I don't understand your issue. What is supposed to happen when you change the roation with the slider, is the cube supposed to rotate ?

Comment: You might find [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-scenegraph.html) useful

Comment: Hi, @Seblor ! Not only the cube should rotate, but the camera along with it

Comment: @ArkadiyVinkovskiy I'm sorry, I really do not understand the problem. Here, your camera rotates along with the cube around the same point, so only the light rotates if you take the camera as reference point.

Comment: @Seblor Yes, it is. But try to pan the camera via right click of your mouse after scene rotation

Comment: @Seblor I updated my question, please look below

Comment: Is this what you're looking to achieve? https://threejs.org/examples/?q=envmap#webgl_materials_envmaps There is also an example using HRD: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=envmap#webgl_materials_envmaps_hdr

Comment: @TheJim01, i know, how to use HDR, but in this question I want to know how to rotate it around the y axis. Read the forums and found out that this is not possible at the moment. The only solution that occurred to me was to rotate the children of the scene, and I almost reached that result. But as you can see in the example above, this method does not work correctly, because after rotating the scene, the controls break